# Algebra-Word Inequality problem: What is the logic behind this question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, word-problem

Question Given:
Ralm is at a super bowl party, and he is the first person to the dessert tray. He loves ice cream sandwiches, but he wants to be considerate to the other people at the party, so he doesn't want to take more than his share. There are 17 people at the party, and there are 40 ice cream sandwiches. If n is the number of ice cream sandwiches Ralm eats, we can write the following inequality to make sure he doesn't exceed his share.
17n≤40

Why would they write an inequality stating that for every sandwhich ralm eats multiply it by 17, I understand it should be less than 40 but why the latter?

Answer (score 0):

If there are 17 people at the party, and each person eats their fair share, how would you represent that algebraically?

Comment: Your statement makes sense but say someone eats two: 17(2)<=40, that means 34<=40, the left side is true to the inequality but what does 34 mean is my question... is it  the number of sandwiches or what?

Comment: @Mustafa The statement *to make sure he doesn't **exceed his share*** is important because it's not just the idea that he can't eat all the sandwiches, he also has to eat an amount that is *fair* for him...

Comment: So by multiplying how many he eats by 17, and knowing there is only 40, 34 can still be equally shared amongst the 17, meaning the fair share is now about 2. I understand to a degree, thank you both for the clarity.

Comment: $17n\le40$ is equivalent to the more meaningful (at least to me) inequality $n\le\frac{40}{17}$.

Comment: @JohnJoy yes that is a much more understandable way to note the inequality, he must eat (n) less than or equal to the fair amount for everyone (40/17).